# ¿Porque no funciona mi menu?

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap

Estoy haciendo una pagina web con bd y todo, modifique un poco el header de una de las partes que hice y decidí copiarlo y pegarlo en las demás, en casi todas funciona menos en una de ellas y no entiendo el porque. este es el código, es bastante, pero a los que se tomen la molestia de leer para ayudarme se los agradesco

```html
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark  bg-dark">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#opciones">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="./usuarios.php">
                <img src="../img/icono.png" width="100px" height="70px" alt="logo"></a>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="opciones"> 
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-1 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown mx-auto">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false">
                                Mi perfil 
                            </a>    
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu color">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="./actualizarUsuario.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>">Actualizar perfil</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Vistas de compras</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Libros descargados</a></li>
                                **<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="./ingresarSugerencia.php">Sugerencias</a></li>** (por alguna razon este es el unico enlace que anda)
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="./cerrarCuenta.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>">Cerrar cuenta</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="./salir.php">Cerrar sesion</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown mx-auto">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false">
                                Control parental 
                            </a>    
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu color">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="./ingresoAVistaControlParental.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>">Ingresar</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="./generarClaveLogeado.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>">Crear Clave</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="./modificarClave.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>">Modificar clave</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="./configuracionControl.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>">Configurar el control Parental</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="./modificacionControlParental.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>">Modificar configuracion</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown mx-auto">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false">
                                Familiares asociados
                            </a>    
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu color">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="./agregarMiembroFamiliar.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>">Agregar familiar</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Abono</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            <nav>
    </header>
```

espero y me puedan ayudar

Comment: A la izquierda, al crear el snippet, aparece la opción "agregar librería externa". Ya que indicás que trabajás con bootstrap, agregá la librería correspondiente. No olvides además ordenar tu código, y describir exactamente cuál es el problema en cuestión.

Comment: ¿en donde aparece esa opción?, porque no la veo

Comment: Debajo de las listas desplegables de la opciones. Es el único botón entre las opciones, de hecho. Y si no lo encontrás, hacé Ctrl + F en el navegador y escribí "Añadir" :) Recordá que esa opción aparece _al editar el snippet_ (tenés que pulsar primero en "editar este fragmento de código").